# Difference between Function Binding and Closure in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, function, closures, bind

When we need to call a javascript function with current context object, I see there are two options like:

1. Using Function Binding
2. Using Javascript Closure

#### Example of Function Binding

```
myProject.prototype.makeAjax = function() {
  $.get('http://www.example.com/todoItems', function success(items) {
   this.addItemsToList(items)
  }.bind(this));
}
```

#### Example of JS Closure

```
myProject.prototype.makeAjax = function() {
  var that = this;

  $.get('http://www.example.com/todoItems', function success(items) {
   that.addItemsToList(items)
  });
}
```

I want to ask:

1. Which of the two is better in terms of performance ?
2. Which should be preferred while writing code ?

Comment: Not sure who voted to close, but I don't think this is too broad? At most point 2 could be argued as subjective but there are concrete reasons to chose one approach or the other.

Comment: @Ian Point 2 is not subjective either. If one approach is better than the other in some situations and other approach in other situations that should answer this. This is what I am looking for. Although I know both can be used interchangeably still I put together point 2 just in case some body adds some wise opinions

Comment: For the particular example shown, I wouldn't think performance would be an issue at all - you're not doing many Ajax calls all at once, are you? But assuming lots of use within a loop, I'd probably start with whichever one you personally prefer and not worry about performance unless you notice a problem.

Comment: @nnnnnn It is not about example. It is more about approach. Performance of approach 1 vs performance of approach 2. I just wrote some dummy examples.

Comment: nice comparison here : http://javascript.info/tutorial/binding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It probably depends a little on which should be preferred. I tend to use the latter (though actually I prefer the former, but some 3rd party libraries we're using limit that). I think the important thing on picking a style is being consistent.

A note for the [prototype.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) is that it's not supported by IE8 and below which might cause you a problem.

I think performance wise, I'd expect `bind` to be a little bit slower as you're calling an extra function in there, but it'll probably depend on browser optimizations. I'll try putting together a `jsperf` example when their site comes back up to answer that part of the question though.

**update**

Seems JSPerf isn't going to be up anytime soon. Here's an snippet that I've put together that shows the closure was quicker (assuming I've done it correct). The closure was slightly more than 7x faster. If you run with the console open you'll see the timings.

```js
var limit = 100000;

var a = {
   val: 0,
   do: function(i) { val = i; /* Actually do some work to ensure doesn't get optimised out */ }  
};

var b = {
   myFunc: function(callback) { callback(); /* Function that's going to change this keyword */}   
};



var start = +new Date();

   for(var i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
     b.myFunc(function() {
        this.do(i);
     }.bind(a));
   };

var end =  +new Date();
var diff = end - start;
console.log("bind took " + diff + " ms");

var start = +new Date();

   for(var i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
     var that = a;
     b.myFunc(function() {
        that.do(i);
     });
   };

var end =  +new Date();
var diff = end - start;

console.log("closured took " + diff + " ms");
```

Comment: Good points..In my knowledge browser saves the current object with function definition while creating the call stack in case of using closures So isn't going to be slower.

Comment: Thanks for the great example..Possible reasoning that closure is faster could be the another function call ?

Comment: @blunderboy other function call? The only other function call I can see is the actual call to `bind(a)` itself, so I believe they should be fairly close.

Comment: Thanks for the beautiful answer. You wrote a nice little script to test performance of both approaches. I will try to gather more info in this regard and if I get I would write up here as an alternative answer.